# Recursive Equations with Time Complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I am really struggling with this recursive question. Can anyone help me solve the recurrence T(n) = 5T (n/5)+5 with the base condition T(1) = 0 via closed-form formula? It is given that n = 5^m with the integer m = log5 n.

Comment: You might want to ask this on one of the math-centric Stackexchange sites.

Comment: OK, I don't understand this "put on hold as too broad".  The explanation is, "there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format".  HUH???  It appears to me that there is *one* correct answer, and that it doesn't need to be very long.  Maybe it should be closed for other reasons, but "too broad"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be sufficient to compute T(5<sup>*n*</sup>) for *n* >= 0.  For all other values of *x*, T(*x*) will equal T(*y*) where *y* is the largest power of 5 smaller than *x*, since the calculations are the same.  (I'm assuming that when you write *n*/5 you mean integer division, i.e. floor(*n*/5).)

Then:

T(5<sup>0</sup>) = 0
T(5<sup>1</sup>) = 5 * 0 + 5 = 5
T(5<sup>2</sup>) = 5 * 5 + 5 = 5<sup>2</sup> + 5<sup>1</sup>
T(5<sup>3</sup>) = 5 * (5 * 5 + 5) + 5 = 5<sup>3</sup> + 5<sup>2</sup> + 5<sup>1</sup>
... which leads to:
T(5<sup>*n*</sup>) = 5<sup>*n*</sup> + 5<sup>*n-1*</sup> + ... + 5<sup>2</sup> + 5<sup>1</sup>

which, using a high-school algebra formula (sum of a geometric series), is

T(5<sup>*n*</sup>) = (5<sup>*n+1*</sup> - 5) / 4

If you're thinking about time complexity, notice that T(*x*) will always be less than or equal to 5x / 4.  And since we don't worry about constant factors when expressing things in O-notation, this essentially means T(*x*) = *O*(*x*).

Answer (score 2):

A non constructive way to solve this: looking a bit at the formula one guesses that T(5<sup>m</sup>) = (5<sup>m+1</sup>-5)/4. This can be shown by induction:

it is correct for m=0: T(1) = 0

assuming it is correct for m we show it for m+1: T(5<sup>m+1</sup>) = T(5*5<sup>m</sup>) = 5T(5<sup>m</sup>)+5 = 5*((5<sup>m+1</sup>-5)/4)+5 = (5<sup>m+2</sup>-25)/4+5 = (5<sup>m+2</sup>-5)/4.

Therefore it is correct for all m.

Comment: Nice, an accurate and effective use of Mathematical Induction.